# Can I use python for a Raspberry Pi based App?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, raspberry-pi3

I'm quite new in coding. I want to control my RC car with my smartphone using a Raspberry Pi 3. My research show that I have to use Node.JS, and consequently JavaScript, to create the App. Is there any way I can do it with Python ? Do you have an open-source exemple?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @gaspardmaraval, welcome to Stack Overflow :D  Please visit [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. :D

Having said that, you may find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+remote+control+mobile) useful.  Happy coding!

Comment: Short answer: yes you can. If you need to access the pins on the Pi there's a guide [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/python/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. That is the only way to program a Raspberry Pi.